# SQL 2012 Profiling - Unresponsive Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion, profiling

Maybe once a week I observe a spate of ColdFusion errors that say, "Connection reset by peer," or "Timed out trying to establish connection." Then everything returns to normal without intervention from me or my DBAs.

It doesn't seem like a network problem. Web pages that don't rely on SQL are served just fine.

SQL memory spikes during the event.

I'd like to figure out why. My responsibilities have been for front end web development, but my DBAs haven't dived in to help. I am hopeful for some advice on where to start.

---

I'd like to know:
What queries are running in SQL at the time of one of these events?
Is there a big one that is over-taxing the server? 
A bunch of little ones?
Is some table being re-indexed? Is some other process occupying the server?

Using CF's SQL monitoring tools, I see several lightweight queries that took 500 seconds to execute. Perhaps these are symptom and not cause. For example:

`INSERT INTO [Our Request Log] (X,Y,Z) VALUES (?,?,NULL)
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('[Our Request Log]') AS 'LastInsertedIdentity',
@@ROWCOUNT AS 'RowsAffectedCount'`

I believe that I ought to investigate the situation using SQL Profiler, which I haven't used before.

But I'm concerned that profiling will be taxing on our production server. I'd test on dev except that there are 1000s of queries spread across 100s of web applications - I can't test each individually. Further, it seems very possible that our problem might stem more from a collection of issues rather than a single query.

Any advice?

---

Our Configuration

- One IIS 6 web server, three IIS 7.5 servers
- One ColdFusion 8 server, three CF 9 servers
- All servers share one MS SQL 2012 server with ~100 databases
- All servers are on VMWare machines - don't know the details offhand but can find out

Comment: Did you mean 500 _milli_ seconds to execute those queries?

Comment: I would want to know if ColdFusion was slow or if SQL Server was slow. I would try doing the insert directly in SSMS to see how long it takes. On the ColdFusion site, I would check to see if there are any non-default settings on the datasource

Comment: I usually associate those, _Connection reset by peer_ and _Timed out trying to establish connection_, as the SQL server being down. Since these are VMWare servers, do you know if your SQL server is moving around during these downtimes (VMotion)? I believe VMWare can be configured to move servers depending on load/processing (and lots of other things). [Example](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-4-esx-vcenter/index.jsp?topic=/com.vmware.vsphere.resourcemanagement.doc_40/creating_a_drs_cluster/c_load_balancing_and_virtual_machine_migration.html)

Comment: No, Miguel, 500 seconds! There are a bunch (10 or 20) of similar queries that took about that long. It seems like they were executing at around the same time.

Comment: As far as running SQL Profiler on a production server see this - [Using SQL Profiler on a database that's in production](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/818/57440)

Comment: James, evidence that it's SQL: 1) Access to SQL via Management Studio VERY slow, 2) CF serves pages that don't have SQL very quickly. We don't alter any of CF's "Advanced" settings for datasources, apart from denying anything but Select, Insert, Update, Delete.

Comment: Miguel, thank you for the link. That seems a good post to start with. And, yes, VMotion is one of the things I'm looking at as a possibility.